# Protractor npm instal in visual studio (Node modules not able to install in visual studio)

Tags: protractor

I am getting this in terminal while running

C:\Users\Admin\protractorpracticecode>npm install
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/jasminee - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'jasminee@3.5.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'protractorpracticecode'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-16T06_24_44_499Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to install `jasminee` with extra `e` at the end. Try to change it to `jasmine`